# Simplifying complex linq query with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, conditional-statements

Recently I have come across the code to fix a bug as shown below. 
It is just hard to understand it and make the changes seem risky as well. 
Is there any easy way to breakdown such a query i.e. De Morgan's law or re-writing in different way.

```
SomeReturnType xyz() 
{
    return (from m in this.context.tblMessages
            where m.SystemActionID.HasValue &&
            (userID == null || m.RecipientID == null || m.RecipientID == userID) &&
            m.TargetUserType == userType &&
            (
                 (territoryID.HasValue && !m.TerritoryID.HasValue) ||
                 (!territoryID.HasValue && !m.TerritoryID.HasValue) ||
                 (territoryID.HasValue && m.TerritoryID.HasValue && territoryID.Value == m.TerritoryID.Value)
            ) &&
            (
                  (regionID.HasValue && !m.RegionID.HasValue) ||
                  (!regionID.HasValue && !m.RegionID.HasValue) ||
                  (regionID.HasValue && m.RegionID.HasValue && regionID.Value == m.RegionID.Value)
            ) &&
            (
                  (teamID.HasValue && !m.TeamID.HasValue) ||
                  (!teamID.HasValue && !m.TeamID.HasValue) ||
                  (teamID.HasValue && m.TeamID.HasValue && teamID.Value == m.TeamID.Value)
            ) &&
            m.SystemActionData == additionalData &&
            (!completed.HasValue || m.IsSystemActionCompleted == completed.Value)
            select m).FirstOrDefault();
}  //function xyz ends
```

Answer (score 3):

First, this code looks like an attempt to move bad SQL code to LINQ: the statements contain parameter checks in an attempt to create a query that can have "optional" parameters. It looks like the author tried to move a stored procedure to code.

Both of these things are really bad ideas.

- First, SQL Server will cache a query's execution plan according to its parameters. This means that the first execution of the procedure determines the plan for all later calls. "Optional" parameters typically result in non-optimal plans (eg by omitting indexes)
- Stored procedures are an abstraction layer that hides complex queries, allows you to use the full SQL syntax of the product. Moving them to code just makes things harder, not easier.
- Finally, LINQ doesn't need "optional" parameters. You can compose your query and the final SQL statement will be generated when you convert the IQueryable to an IEnumerable. In this case, when you call FirstOrDefault.

For example, you can change this:

```
(from m in this.context.tblMessages
        where m.SystemActionID.HasValue &&
        (userID == null || m.RecipientID == null || m.RecipientID == userID) &&
        m.TargetUserType == userType &&
        (
             (territoryID.HasValue && !m.TerritoryID.HasValue) ||
             (!territoryID.HasValue && !m.TerritoryID.HasValue) ||
             (territoryID.HasValue && m.TerritoryID.HasValue && territoryID.Value == m.TerritoryID.Value)
        ) &&
```

to this

```
if (userId==null)
    return null;
var query=from m in this.context.tblMessages
        where m.SystemActionID != null 
              && (m.RecipientID == null || m.RecipientID == userID)
              && m.TargetUserType == userType ;
if (territoryID.HasValue)
    query=query.Where(m=>m.TerritoryId==null || m.TerritoryId==teritoryID);
```

You can simplify the rest of the statement in the same way, eg:

```
if (regionID.HasValue)
    query=query.Where(m=>m.RegionId==null || m.RegionId==regionID);
if (teamID.HasValue)
    query=query.Where(m=>m.TeamID==null || m.TeamID==teamID);
```

The LINQ query should never compare parameters against constants - why force the server to do a constantc check you can easily do on the client?

This will result in queries that are a lot simpler and easier for the server to optimize

Answer (score 1):

I am using IQueryable in such cases. I have used some dummy names instead of your example to demonstrate idea itself - you need to apply "where" clauses step by step.

```
IQueryable<Account> query1 = from account in storage.Accounts
                                where account.Username == username
                                select account;

IQueryable<SomeNewTypeIfNecessary> query2 = from account in query1
                                            where account.ID > 100
                                            select new SomeNewTypeIfNecessary { ID = account.ID };

// Final call doing real query to database.
List<SomeNewTypeIfNecessary> accounts = query2.ToList();
```

In addition such technique allows to dynamically add desired statements (mostly where and orderby clauses) to get specific data dependent on some user choice (for example sort direction).

Comment: LINQ *is* using IQueryable.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: What exactly do you mean? I told that I need IQueryable to store intermediate result (some expression tree) instead of performing query in the same statement. Please read carefully source before any comments.

Comment: There are no intermediate results. An IQueryable is an abstraction of a query, not the results of the query. What you are doing is *composing* a query. In fact, you could rewrite your code as `query2=query1.Where(account=>account.ID>100); query3=query2.Select(...)` and the results would be exactly the same. In the end only one query will be sent to the server, when you call `ToList()`;

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Where did I say about intermediate results of QUERY (any rows, fetched data, etc)? I told about intermediate result meaning "some expression tree". Please read text inside parentheses as well. So "query1.Where(account=>account.ID>100).Select(...)" will produce exactly IQueryable, but we told about the way to SPLIT complex statement in multiple ones. And IQueryable is exactly type to store intermediate expression and all next expressions will use corresponding previous one as base.